# Php: How does form submission work?

Tags: php, post, get

I am fairly new to PHP.

The code is pretty simple:

`home.php:`

```
<form action="getsentitem.php" method="get">
   <div  >
   <input  name="query" id="query" class="searchQuery" size="20" value="" type="text" autocomplete="off">
   <input id="searchButton" value="Search" type="submit">
   </div>
</form>
```

`getsentitem.php:`

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['query']))
$query = $_GET['query'];

?>
```

Question:
The above code will simply give me whatever I enter in the text box which is there in `home.php`. Now, is there any way through which I can get the values of the other attributes of the text box? Like, is it possible to get the id of the textbox or its size through this method.

Comment: That isn't possible, submitting forms to php only transfers the value and name in array from GET or POST if method='post'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it is not. Only name=>value pairs are sent to the server via your chosen method (GET/POST).

You can include custom data in hidden inputs within the form if you want to:

```
<form action="getsentitem.php" method="get">
   <div  >
   <input type="hidden" name="more_info" value="I will be available after submit."/>
   <input  name="query" id="query" class="searchQuery" size="20" value="" type="text" autocomplete="off">
   <input id="searchButton" value="Search" type="submit">
   </div>
</form>

echo $_GET['more_info']; // 'I will be available after submit.'
```

This is handy when you generate additional data via AJAX calls and javascript calculations. You don't necessarily know all the IDs of a highly dynamic webpage.

[CSRF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery) tokens are also usually sent this way.

---

Comment: Even though I agree with deceze's answer, that the ID should be known in the first place since it's pure HTML, this is a good thing to know about forms.

Comment: NOw, that was what I was looking fr. Thanks a lot. :) Needed something like this. Will accept your answer when 9 minutes are dome ;) Thanks thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

No. Only the entered value is submitted with the name you gave it, nothing else; you can see exactly what gets submitted in the URL, that's it. Since you created the HTML in the first place, you should know what the other values were.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is: `NO`

You can only get the value of the input from the `$_GET` superarray.

edit.

However if you did something like this:

```
<form action="getsentitem.php" method="get">
   <div  >
   <input  name="query" id="query" class="searchQuery" size="20" value="" type="text" autocomplete="off">
   <input name="queryMeta" value="id:query_class:searchQuery_size:20" type="hidden">
   <input id="searchButton" value="Search" type="submit">
   </div>
</form>
```

Then you can read it in the PHP like this:

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['queryMeta']))
$queryMeta = explode('_',$_GET['queryMeta']); //splits the string to array('id:query','class:searchQuery','size:20')
?>
```

Comment: The long answer: `NOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO`.

Comment: Why concat data into one field when you can have an infinity of them floating around? I don't think this is a good practice.

Comment: @MaximKumpan I think it's better to have it clustered like this for a number of reasons. First of all - it doesn't mess the output form that much + it's less code to send + for me it's easier to distinguish between inputs with meta values and the rest. Personally I wouldn't pass the atributes that way, but I thought it may be quite nice for the OP to get what he wants.